# Modernizr check for object-fit not giving expected result

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, modernizr

I am creating a fallback for `object-fit` using Modernizr. The solution is working, but instead of only applying it to browsers that don't support `object-fit` (like IE), it applies the code to all browsers. Why is that?

My code:

```
if ( ! Modernizr.objectfit ) {
    console.log('object fit is not supported');
    tpj('.featuredpost').each(function () {
        var $container = tpj(this),
                imgUrl = $container.find('.img-responsive').prop('src');
        if (imgUrl) {
            $container
                .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
                .addClass('compat-object-fit');
        }
    });

    tpj('.big-post').each(function () {
        var $container = tpj(this),
                imgUrl = $container.find('.img-responsive').prop('src');
        if (imgUrl) {
            $container
                .css('backgroundImage', 'url(' + imgUrl + ')')
                .addClass('compat-object-fit');
        }
    });
}else{
    console.log('object is supported');
}
```

No matter what browser I check, it always logs: `object fit is not supported` even on browsers that support `object-fit`.

What can I do about this?

Modernizr is correctly included and loaded (even if I change the local file to a CDN path, I get the same result):

```
<!-- Modernizr Library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: *"Modernizr is correctly included and loaded"* => can you let us judge about it? Please provide an [MCVE]. And for what it's worth, I can't repro on FF58  nor on chrome 63. https://jsfiddle.net/02u39z1z/

Comment: @Kaiido Added to post

Comment: That doesn't constitute an [MCVE] yet.

Comment: @Kaiido I think it does now?

Comment: Did you get modernizr from its website, checking CSS ObjectFit from features list? https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses&q=objectFit.
You can verify if objectfit is actually included in your library by searching for `Modernizr.addTest("objectfit"` ...  inside your modernizr.js.
Also, some CDN js files do not include objectFit.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using an old version of Modernizr. Make sure that you are using the full Modernizr 3.x or a [custom Modernizr 3.x build](https://modernizr.com/download?setclasses) with `CSS Object Fit` feature check.

[See example with custom Modernizr build on Codepen](https://codepen.io/layzee/pen/ppmrgL?editors=1111)

Comment: Yep, is a bug fixed on `v3.0`: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1607